# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in AT&T assembly code

Tags: assembly

I've written a simple program in assembly language, trying to run it on my 64bit Ubuntu OS. However, it failed for the "Segmentation fault (core dumped) error ".

Here is my code :

```
    .section .data
    values :
        .int 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 ,35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60
    output :
        .asciz "The value is %d\n"
   .section .text
   .globl main
   main :
        nop
        movl $0, %edi
   loop :
        movl values( , %edi, 4), %eax
        pushq %rax
        pushq $output
        call printf
        addl $8, %esp
        inc %edi
        cmpl $11, %edi
        jne loop
        movl $0, %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

Comment: I think the majority of your `e__` registers should be `r__`. It seems like this was written as x86 assembly, and forcibly ported to x64 without making all the necessary changes.

Comment: I have tried it, but it can't work, either.

Comment: Assembled as 64bit?  Then the stack is not DWORD but QWORD aligned, so your adding 8 to rsp is wrong, should be adding 16 to rsp after your printf call

Comment: You're right, there is a mistake here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code.

From `64bit Ubuntu` and `pushq %rax` I infer that you're trying to make a 64-bit executable.

If that's the case, then...

Here:

```
pushq %rax
pushq $output
call printf
addl $8, %esp
```

you're not properly balancing the stack after the function call. You still remember that this is 64-bit code? You need to add to `rsp`, not `esp`. Also, if you push 2 8-byte parameters, you have to remove exactly 2 8-byte parameters, which means you have to add 16, not 8.

But it's even worse than that. In 64-bit mode parameters are passed differently. The first parameters are in the registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8` and `r9`. So, that gives us:

```
movq %rax, %rsi
movq $output, %rdi
movq $0, %rax ; number of vector registers used for var-arg-function printf()
call printf
```

Here:

```
inc %edi
```

You just destroyed the value of `rdi` by the call and by using this register for parameter passing. You need to manually push `rdi` prior to the call and then pop it back. Or you could save it in a global variable. If you choose to push and pop, make sure than the stack pointer `rsp` is always 16-byte-aligned before any `call` instruction.

Here:

```
movl $0, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

you are using the 32-bit system call interface. In 64-bit programs you have to use the 64-bit system call interface:

```
movq $60, %rax ; sys_exit
movq $0, rdi ; return 0 (success)
syscall
```

Now, I think this one may have problems too:

```
movl $0, %edi
loop :
movl values( , %edi, 4), %eax
```

In general, you shouldn't be using 32-bit registers and 32-bit instructions in address calculations in 64-bit code. I'd change it to:

```
movl $0, %rdi
loop :
movl values( , %rdi, 4), %eax
```

If neither of the two works because the address of `values` is more than 2GB away from `rip` (fact: displacements are limited to 32-bit signed integers in memory operands in most instructions in 64-bit mode and most of them have no displacement-only memory operand encoding in 64-bit mode either, they use `rip`-relative addressing there), you will need to manually add the 64-bit address of `values` and the index into the array multiplied by 4. Make sure you do a 64-bit addition without any truncations along the way.

Must-reads:

- System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement Draft Version 0.99.6
- Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems By Agner Fog

Comment: You're so kind. Thank you very much. I'm reading the book PROFESSIONAL ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE, whose code samples were all written on 32bit OS, so I encounter a lot of problems when I tested them on my 64bit OS. Thank you again!